# Making a constexpr binary mask out of enum values and with a variadic template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, constexpr, bitmask

I am trying to make a class for generating constexpr bitmasks out of enum values.

However, I get several compilation errors with the code below, especially:

- `makeMask(args...)` has "expected ')' " error
- The `FruitMask` can't be a constant expression

What am I doing wrong?

```
enum Fruit
{
    Banana,
    Apple,
    Orange,
    Kiwi,
    Coconut,
    Strawberry
};

struct FruitMask
{
    static constexpr int makeMask() { return 0; }
    template<typename ... Args> static constexpr int makeMask(Fruit fruit, Args ... args)
    {
        static_assert((int)fruit< (sizeof(mask)*8), "Mask values too large");
        return (1 << (int)mode) | makeMask(args ...);
    }
    template<typename ... Args> constexpr FruitMask(Args ... args) { mask = makeMask(args...); }
    int mask;
};

static constexpr const FruitMask ExoticFruitMask = FruitMask(Banana, Coconut);
```

EDIT : The design is as intented : Fruit items will have default iterative integer values 0,1,2,3... and FruitMask will be the corresponding bitmask. FruitMask values are not expected to be compared or binary combined with Fruit cast to int.

Everything works if I remove the constexprs. It seems not possible to make a constexpr recursive variadic template?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make static_assert through this, but you can use  `return ((1ull << args) | ... | 0);` - this'll handle anything up to 63 (including constructor without parameters)

Comment: I have the same errors without  the static_assert, so I commented it. It still doesn't compile. It's just there as an insurance the Fruit class cannot grow beyond the available number of bits.

Comment: I've got it working:  https://godbolt.org/z/nef859veY

Comment: @KIIV - interesting... your code compile with C++20 (c++2a) but not with C++17. What's changed in C++20 that make this code valid?

Comment: @KIIV - and for clang++, your example is OK also in C++17. A g++ bug?

Comment: @KIIV i'm not sure what your code does with | ... | but you are OR'ing with the raw Fruit ints and not their bit shifted value, this completely changes the result

Comment: @galinette result for the banana and coconut is 17 ->  1 << 0 | 1 << 4  ->   1 | 16 = 17

Comment: @KIIV damn you are right, that syntax and how it unrolls the ... is really a mystery to me... Still, even if my design with the recursive variadic approach is less elegant, why isn't it compiling?

Comment: Also, it now accepts any int or enum, not only Fruit values, so the result isn't strictly the same

Comment: I'm not sure, on that Compiler explorer it won't compile on  gcc 6.1 + c++17, but gcc 6.4 compiles it

Comment: This fold expression compiles on gcc 6.1 C++17: `return ( ... | (1 << args) )`.  There is a bug in gcc 6.1 with right fold expressions.